# How can I play a sound from the command line running as sudo?

Tags: terminal, audio, sudo

While typing `afplay danger.mp3` in the Terminal will play the .mp3, doing `sudo afplay danger.mp3` or `sudo su` and then `afplay danger.mp3` does not.

Any idea why is this? How can I use the `afplay` command with **sudo/su**?

Comment: Ok this is totally weird.  I looked at the console app and when I "sudo afplay" I see this 7/29/12 7:29:52.567 PM coreaudiod[140]: 2012-07-29 07:29:52.566586 PM [AirPlay] Stopping endpoint 'Living Room Apple TV'
7/29/12 7:29:52.630 PM coreaudiod[140]: 2012-07-29 07:29:52.629656 PM [AirPlay] Disconnected from [fe80::5a55:caff:fe0e:8cba%en0]:49152 (from [fe80::223:dfff:fefd:b8b5%en0]:53791)
7/29/12 7:29:52.631 PM coreaudiod[140]: 2012-07-29 07:29:52.631078 PM [AirPlay] Stopped endpoint 'Living Room Apple TV'

Comment: I don't see those entries in the console when I run afplay without sudo.   Also I verified my sound is set to go to the internal speaker.  FYI--I am using Mountain Lion

Comment: Works for me with sudo for local sound output. Are you trying to play the sound over Airplay ?

Comment: I'm not trying to but thats would it seems like its doing.  I checked my system preferences and sound output it set to "Internal speakers" although I do see my two air play devices also listed.    Its weird the problem only occurs when I run afplay as sudo or su

Comment: I can't reproduce it either. Have you tried disabling the AirPlay devices?